# CSS Text Background-Color gets cut off

Tags: css, text, background-color

First of all, this is the guideline aswell as what I want to achieve:

[image]

It doesn't need to look a 100% alike but at least one space at each EndOfLine should be given. Well, this is what happens when I try to do it:

[image]

As you can see, the end of the first line as well as the beginning of the second line have no space to the border. The start of the first line and the end of the second line on the other hand, do have a space.

Here is my HTML- & CSS-Markup.

```
<div class="headline-h2">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</h2>
</div>


h2 {
background-color: #000000;
clear: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 4px;
position: relative;
}

.headline-h2 {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 28px !important;
width: 100%;
}
```

I already tried a few things but I cannot for my life work this thing out.
I also have to add that the text is variable, therefore it could be something completely different if the customer wants it.
Also it needs to be said that we EXPLICITLY need this for an inline-element. I know that it works with block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `padding` to your `h2`:

```
h2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    clear: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I already have a padding of 4px, I just forgot to add the code here. The picture in my post is with 4px of padding.

Comment: The problem is that it extends to the width of the parent div, and not to the width of the text.

Comment: To be more specific - I need it to work with an inline element.

Comment: @NoReply - Don't think you can have padding applied the way you want on an inline element.

Comment: @BillyMoat - Yeah, that's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure there was no "hack" or easy way to resolve to problem.

Comment: @NoReply Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JnLje/) and apply for your situation